# LdapContext vs dircontext in JNDI

Tags: java, active-directory, jndi

Please explain the difference between using `ldapcontext` and `dircontext` in JNDI.

I found that there are JNDI samples using both `ldapcontext` and `dircontext`. Which should I use?

Comment: Jean, thx for the grammar fix :)

Comment: What part of their respective Javadocs didn't you understand?

Comment: sorry i missed the javadocs description, i don't know about LDAPV3 stuff, but, because i just use simple operations, i'll use DirContext instead. Thanks

Comment: You 'missed' it? You need to get into the habit of looking for it. Internet help sites are for when you don't understand, not when you don't even look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From JavaDocs about ldapcontext

> This interface represents a context in which you can perform
>   operations with LDAPv3-style controls and perform LDAPv3-style
>   extended operations. For applications that do not require such
>   controls or extended operations, the more generic
>   javax.naming.directory.DirContext should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Most search function on ldap can be done using the base DirContext.
but in my case i need to use LdapContext becasue i got a large amount of entries in the query result. for that case i needed to loop on the results which includes usinge pagesize filter. this filter is available on the LdapContext.
for that case you can cast the base DirContext to get LdapContext.

for example the **setRequestControls** function is only available on LdapContext.

for more info check the official [Interface LdapContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/LdapContext.html)

```
LdapContext ldapContext = getLdapContext()
int pageSize = 900;
byte[] cookie = null;
Control[] requestControls = new Control[] { new PagedResultsControl(pageSize, Control.NONCRITICAL) };
ldapContext .setRequestControls(requestControls);
```